# How does bonus experience on weapons work?

Tags: diablo-iii

I currently have a bunch of equipment that gives experience bonuses, **but how do equipped weapons give experience?** I have a sword that gives a +10 experience per kill, but do I have to use the weapon in the kill to gain the bonus?

Since I am using the Witch Doctor as my class and most of my kills are from a distance with magic, so I wasn't sure how that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you do not have to use the weapon to get the kill.**

The majority of the games characters do not directly use their weapons in their attacks. Most of them are just ways to bolster stats and give a baseline for damage. The monk, for instance, is a highly melee focused class, but does not use his weapons (unless they are fist weapons).

That bonus you see on the weapon is added to your cumulative bonus total.

Answer (score 0):

This is a character level stat, as you can see on the Details screen on the character sheet.  It doesn't matter how you get the kill, any time that you would get X experience from killing a monster, you instead get X+10.